# How to connect two geometry objects with a path?

Tags: c#, wpf, geometry, drawing, shapes

I have a `CombinedGeometry` that represents the shape of a brush. It could look like this for example:[image: Shape of a brush]

From that, I would like to generate a `PathGeometry` or a `GeometryGroup`, that looks like a stroke of that brush.

The brush from my example should give me something like:
[image: Stroke of the brush]

Drawing the startpoint and the endpoint of my stroke is quite easy:

```
public GeometryGroup CreateStroke(CombinedGeometry brushGeo, Point ptStart, Point ptEnd)
{
    var geoStart = brushGeo.Clone();
    geoStart.Transform = new TranslateTransform(ptStart.X, ptStart.Y);

    var geoEnd = brushGeo.Clone();
    geoEnd.Transform = new TranslateTransform(ptEnd.X, ptEnd.Y);

    var result = new GeometryGroup();
    result.Children.Add(geoStart);
    result.Children.Add(geoEnd);
}
```

But how can I add the connection between the points?